# How to create SSL certificate in Azure.?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dns, ssl-certificate, namecheap

I purchased my domain from namecheap.com. And then I created the DNS Zone in azure where I was able to manage dns records easily. I want to create an application gateway where i need to attach an ssl certificate for ssl termination. But for this i should already have the certificate with. Is there any way i can get or create the free ssl certificate in azure and attach it to my application gateway. Is there any service like AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) in Azure which can help me to create free ssl certificate.

I tried to create the certificate from LetsEncrypt and i was able to attach it to application gateway. But is there any another secure or more azure specific way to create the ssl certificate.?

Comment: Yes,you can create SSL Certificate from Powershell by using the `New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ -DnsName www.****.com` command.

Comment: To check the certificate run [`certmgr.msc`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbvCU.png) in the windows and check for Personal  => [Certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koY4F.png).

Comment: But in that case it will be a SelfSignedCertificate, and ideally we should not use SelfSignedCertificate for production environment 
Also not with LetsEncrypt, Basically want to use certain kind of trusted certificates like AWS-ACM

Comment: This is off-topic here (not a programming question). Perhaps it fits on [sf] or [su] - just read the guidelines there first.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create an application gateway where I need to attach an ssl certificate for ssl termination is there any another secure or more azure specific way to create the ssl certificate.

To attach SSL certificate for an Application gateway you can make use of key vault certificate check the below workarounds.

Create a key vault in Azure portal like below:

[image]

Created key with key type RSA and size with 2048:

[image]

Generate a certificate like below:

[image]
.
[image]

You can download a certificate like below:

[image]

Create a Managed identity, Add your managed identity in key vault access policies like below:

Make sure to assign RBAC role in key vault **`Key vault Administrator role`** in Access control (IAM) like below:

Click Access policies. -> create -> select ***secret management*** -> add your ***Managed identity*** in `principal` and save

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, In Application gateway I am able to attach SSL certificate like below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Is this certificate free of cost.? And can I create the wild card certificate from it?

Comment: Yes it's free of cost and create wild card certificate check this reference https://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2022/05/07/use-azure-key-vault-store-of-wild-card-certificate-created-via-certbot-and-update-the-local-nginx-webserver-and-azure-application-gateway/

Comment: I created the certificate but it is showing as the connection is not secure.
Below is the response with the curl request:
➜  ~ curl https://test.example.com/
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Comment: Once again... please stop posting images of text in answers - [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, the question is off-topic here (not a programming question)

Comment: hello @Imran, we are looking for a specialist, who can help us setup App Gateway with wildcard certificate stored in Key Vault